# linux: can't set cpu frequency governor with cpupower

Tags: linux, cpu, power-management, cpu-frequency, amd

I have a server HPE ProLiant system with AMD Epyc CPU, BIOS A43 v1.20, with Linux kernel 4.19.71 (as well I tried on 5.4.0). Now, I'm trying to set CPU performance governor:

```
# cpupower frequency-set -g performance
    Setting cpu: 0
    Error setting new values. Common errors:
    - Do you have proper administration rights? (super-user?)
    - Is the governor you requested available and modprobed?
    - Trying to set an invalid policy?
    - Trying to set a specific frequency, but userspace governor is not available,
       for example because of hardware which cannot be set to a specific frequency
       or because the userspace governor isn't loaded?
#
```

So I begin troubleshooting:

```
# cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: Not Available
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: Not Available
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
Not Available
  available cpufreq governors: Not Available
  Unable to determine current policy
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency:  Unable to call to kernel
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    Boost States: 0
    Total States: 3
    Pstate-P0:  2000MHz
    Pstate-P1:  1800MHz
    Pstate-P2:  1500MHz
#
# ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/
<Empty>
#
#
```

So, for whatever reason, it thinks that `cpufreq` drivers are missing. However, the kernel `.config` has the following enabled:

```
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ=y
CONFIG_X86_ACPI_CPUFREQ=y
CONFIG_X86_ACPI_CPUFREQ_CPB=y
CONFIG_X86_INTEL_PSTATE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_PERFORMANCE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_PERFORMANCE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_ONDEMAND=y
```

I did try to disable `CONFIG_X86_INTEL_PSTATE` and add `CONFIG_X86_POWERNOW_K8` (the only AMD-specific in the current kernel), but it didn't seem to help.

I would be happy for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite likely that if you are using the second generation of EPYC CPU (Rome), not all function are implemented on your kernel. I don't know which distro you are using (it could be backported), but according to this blogpost on Ubuntu https://ubuntu.com/blog/amd-epyc-rome-support-in-ubuntu-server your kernel might not fully support your CPU.

From the Ubuntu site:

**Support for AMD EPYC Rome has been merged to the Linux kernel starting with 5.4 series. Therefore, all Ubuntu releases with 5.4 kernel installed support this CPU and all its new features. However, Canonical has also backported basic support for AMD EPYC Rome to older LTS releases to ensure they will work properly on this new CPU.**

Comment: @Mark if I were you I would create new question. The questions with accepted answers are not as rewarding as one without it :D! You can also scrub old data that might confuse people.