# linux: poor ACPI support on AMD Epyc?

Tags: linux, power-management, acpi, amd, cpu-frequency

I have a server HPE ProLiant system with AMD Epyc CPU, BIOS A43 v1.20, with Linux kernel 5.4.0.

`cpupower` always reports no available drivers and as a result I can't set CPU frequencies (details in my other question [linux: can't set cpu frequency governor with cpupower](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628831/linux-cant-set-cpu-frequency-governor-with-cpupower/629713?noredirect=1#comment1182075_629713)) :

```
# cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: Not Available
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: Not Available
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
Not Available
  available cpufreq governors: Not Available
  Unable to determine current policy
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency:  Unable to call to kernel
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    Boost States: 0
    Total States: 3
    Pstate-P0:  2000MHz
    Pstate-P1:  1800MHz
    Pstate-P2:  1500MHz
#
# ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/
<Empty>
#
#
```

My efforts to debug the drivers behaviour -- drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq.c and drivers/cpufreq/acpi-cpufreq.c have revealed that `acpi-cpufreq` actually fails with message:

**ACPI-based processor performance control unavailable**

Call chain is as follows:

```
cpufreq_add_dev()
  -> cpufreq_online(cpu)
        -> cpufreq_driver->init()  [*]

[*]
acpi_cpufreq_cpu_init()
   -> acpi_processor_register_performance()
         -> acpi_processor_get_performance_info()
             <return -EIO>
```

As far as I understand, in acpi_processor_get_performance_info() the driver attempts to read _PCT object from ACPI table and fails, because can't find it.

Does this mean that the BIOS has no full support of ACPI, or CPU microcode needs to be updated, or the kernel is missing something?

I would be happy for any advice/comment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved after I set the following parameter in the BIOS:

```
BIOS/Platform Configuration
     -> Power and Performance Options
          -> Power Regulator
               [*] OS Control Mode
```

Apparently it allows OS to change `P-states` and check the status of `P-state` requests etc.