# Cannot set CPU frequency

Tags: linux, cpu, amd

I‘m trying to set my CPU max frequency to the max value supplied by `scaling_available_frequencies`, but it looks like the kernel is simply ignoring me.

My kernel:

```
# uname -a
Linux valfenda 5.10.32-051032-generic #202104210836 SMP Wed Apr 21 13:18:19 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But it was the same using 5.8.

My processor is AMD Ryzen 7 4700U with Radeon Graphics, 8 cores.

```
# cpufreq-info -c0
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 1.40 GHz - 2.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.00 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.40 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 1.40 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.40 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 2.00 GHz:0.05%, 1.70 GHz:0.04%, 1.40 GHz:99.91%  (199)
```

Pay attention at the line: `frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 1.40 GHz`.

I tried:

```
# cat scaling_available_frequencies
2000000 1700000 1400000
# cut -d' ' -f1 scaling_available_frequencies > scaling_max_freq
# cat scaling_max_freq
1400000
```

And:

```
# cpufreq-set -u2GHz
# cpufreq-info | ag 'current policy'
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 1.40 GHz.
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 1.40 GHz.
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 1.40 GHz.
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 1.40 GHz.
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 1.40 GHz.
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 1.40 GHz.
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 1.40 GHz.
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.40 GHz and 1.40 GHz.
```

No difference.

My modules:

```
# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
msr                    16384  0
btrfs                1351680  0
blake2b_generic        20480  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              114688  1 btrfs
ufs                    81920  0
qnx4                   16384  0
hfsplus               110592  0
hfs                    61440  0
minix                  45056  0
ntfs                  106496  0
msdos                  20480  0
jfs                   196608  0
xfs                  1511424  0
rfcomm                 81920  4
nf_conntrack_netlink    49152  0
xfrm_user              36864  1
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
xt_addrtype            16384  2
br_netfilter           28672  0
ccm                    20480  6
xt_CHECKSUM            16384  1
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  4
xt_conntrack           16384  2
cmac                   16384  5
algif_hash             16384  2
ipt_REJECT             16384  2
algif_skcipher         16384  2
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
af_alg                 32768  10 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
xt_tcpudp              20480  9
ip6table_mangle        16384  1
ip6table_nat           16384  1
iptable_mangle         16384  1
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat                 49152  3 ip6table_nat,iptable_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack          147456  4 xt_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_netlink,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
nf_tables             208896  0
libcrc32c              16384  5 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,btrfs,nf_tables,xfs
nfnetlink              20480  3 nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_tables
ip6table_filter        16384  1
ip6_tables             32768  3 ip6table_filter,ip6table_nat,ip6table_mangle
iptable_filter         16384  1
bpfilter               16384  0
bridge                233472  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
bnep                   24576  2
overlay               131072  0
joydev                 28672  0
amdgpu               5988352  40
snd_hda_codec_realtek   139264  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     65536  1
snd_hda_intel          53248  5
iommu_v2               20480  1 amdgpu
iwlmvm                413696  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
soundwire_intel        40960  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
gpu_sched              40960  1 amdgpu
soundwire_generic_allocation    16384  1 soundwire_intel
soundwire_cadence      32768  1 soundwire_intel
ttm                   102400  1 amdgpu
snd_acp3x_pdm_dma      16384  1
snd_hda_codec         147456  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
mac80211              970752  1 iwlmvm
drm_kms_helper        233472  1 amdgpu
snd_hda_core           94208  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_acp3x_rn           16384  1
soundwire_bus          77824  3 soundwire_intel,soundwire_generic_allocation,soundwire_cadence
snd_soc_dmic           16384  1
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
cec                    53248  1 drm_kms_helper
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
snd_soc_core          282624  4 soundwire_intel,snd_acp3x_rn,snd_soc_dmic,snd_acp3x_pdm_dma
rc_core                57344  1 cec
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
binfmt_misc            24576  1
btusb                  57344  0
kvm_amd               102400  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
iwlwifi               376832  1 iwlmvm
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
kvm                   798720  1 kvm_amd
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_pcm               118784  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_acp3x_pdm_dma,snd_pcm_dmaengine
btintel                28672  1 btusb
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
bluetooth             651264  31 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
aesni_intel           372736  11
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  4 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd                    94208  25 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
cfg80211              843776  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
soundcore              16384  1 snd
ecc                    32768  1 ecdh_generic
input_leds             16384  0
snd_rn_pci_acp3x       20480  0
rapl                   20480  0
ccp                   102400  1 kvm_amd
snd_pci_acp3x          20480  0
serio_raw              20480  0
hp_wmi                 20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
efi_pstore             16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
hid_multitouch         28672  0
k10temp                16384  0
ucsi_acpi              16384  0
typec_ucsi             36864  1 ucsi_acpi
typec                  53248  1 typec_ucsi
mac_hid                16384  0
hp_accel               28672  0
lis3lv02d              24576  1 hp_accel
hp_wireless            16384  0
acpi_tad               20480  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
cuse                   16384  3
parport_pc             45056  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   548864  20 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,ttm
ip_tables              32768  3 iptable_filter,iptable_nat,iptable_mangle
x_tables               45056  12 ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,xt_CHECKSUM,ip6_tables,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,ip6table_mangle,xt_MASQUERADE,iptable_mangle
autofs4                45056  2
hid_generic            16384  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         28672  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
nvme                   45056  4
ahci                   40960  0
rtsx_pci               94208  1 rtsx_pci_sdmmc
i2c_piix4              28672  0
xhci_pci               20480  0
libahci                36864  1 ahci
nvme_core             122880  6 nvme
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
wmi                    32768  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof
video                  49152  0
i2c_hid                32768  0
hid                   135168  3 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
```

I’ve seen other similar questions, but no satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I have an up-to-date RHEL-9.2 running on:

- Computer: Dell XPS L412Z (aka 14Z - c. 2011)
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9
- kernel-5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64 - recent `dnf update`
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz
- Battery pack: DELL YMYF6252 (clone?)

The problem I had was the same as yours...

i.e No matter what I did, my computer was stuck running at 798 MHz, even when I loaded the CPUs up, each of the 4 CPUs running `while true; do true; done`, the stayed stubbornly at 798 MHz.

I tried all `cpufreq governors`: conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil

Even rebooting has no effect.  But I did find a ***weird*** workaround.

```
# cpupower -c 0 frequency-info ↲
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 20.0 us
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 3.50 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 3.50 MHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 798 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    3300 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
    3300 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
    3300 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
    3500 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
```

The fans stubbornly stayed at low speed, and the CPU/Core temperatures were around +50.0°C:

```
# sensors ↲
...
Package id 0:  +54.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

The fix?

- unplug the Laptop from it's AC Power adapter...

Suddenly the 4 × `while true; do true; done &` loaded Laptop's fans sped up, and I found the CPU's were now running at: 2.72 GHz!!

**Now the CPU's and fan have all sped up.:**

```
# cpupower -c 0 frequency-info ↲
...
  current CPU frequency: 2.82 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
```

Then I plugged in the AC Power adapter, and the DELL Laptop is performing great. **Weird**

The Laptop is subsequently revert to being stuck on 798 MHz.  And the unplug, re-plug power did fix the issue.  But a Laptop suspend/resume (or maybe a power cycle) with AC Power adapter **unplugged** seemed to resolve the issue.

This is a good enough workaround for my Laptop.  But it looks like there is a similar underlying bug that has been around for a few years... eg.

**Similar issues elsewhere:**

- 2021: [linux: can't set cpu frequency governor with cpupower](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628831/linux-cant-set-cpu-frequency-governor-with-cpupower)
- 2021: [linux: can't set cpu frequency governor with cpupower (ACPI failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65688651/linux-cant-set-cpu-frequency-governor-with-cpupower-acpi-failure)
- 2018: [SOLVED - CPU frequency stuck at 800MHz](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-XPS-9550-CPU-Multiplier-Stuck-at-8/td-p/4740654)
- 2018: [SOLVED - Dell XPS 9550 CPU Multiplier Stuck at 8](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=241593)
- 2017: [cpufrequtils shows my CPU can perform at a higher frequency... why can't I hit max freq?](https://superuser.com/questions/1180655/cpufrequtils-shows-my-cpu-can-perform-at-a-higher-frequency-why-cant-i-hit-m)
- 2017: [Strange cpufreq scaling issues: regardless of governor, max cpufreq drops incrementally on wake](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740108/strange-cpufreq-scaling-issues-regardless-of-governor-max-cpufreq-drops-increm)- 2017: [Why won't my CPU operate at its max potential even when my application (which utilize CPU's resources) is lagging?](https://superuser.com/questions/1264798/why-wont-my-cpu-operate-at-its-max-potential-even-when-my-application-which-ut)
- 2012: [Processor remains underclocked even under load](https://superuser.com/questions/443906/processor-remains-underclocked-even-under-load)
- 2011: [cpufreq policy acting weird, current policy max gets throttled](https://superuser.com/questions/271064/cpufreq-policy-acting-weird-current-policy-max-gets-throttled)

Answer (score 0):

The following sets all the cpu cores to maximum frequency. you may need to install utility cpupower.

```
cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance
```

Comment: I got a problem using cpupower: WARNING: cpupower not found for kernel 5.10.32-051032

Comment: Anyway, when I was using the kernel 5.8, I tried that, and the max frequency didn’t change.